# How to wrap a facelet in a <p:ajax> element

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I have a `<p:dataTable>` in a facelet. The facelet is included into a page. A selection of a table row should trigger an update on an element of the surrounding page.

When I include the `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":open:separate" />` inside the table, all works fine. But I am using the table on multiple pages and cannot guarantee a constant Id for the updated element.

I have tried removing the `<p:ajax>` from the table and wrap the included table inside it like this:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":open:separate">
    <ui:include src="/open/components/submittersTable.xhtml"/>
</p:ajax>
```

I get this error (root cause abridged):

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /open/index.xhtml @30,59 <p:ajax> Event:rowSelect is not supported.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)

root cause

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /open/index.xhtml @30,59 <p:ajax> Event:rowSelect is not supported.
    org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorHandler.applyAttachedObject(AjaxBehaviorHandler.java:148)
    org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorHandler.apply(AjaxBehaviorHandler.java:126)
```

Am I having wrong ideas about what is possible with `<p:ajax>`? Do I have to include it into the table and try forcing the ids on the surrounding pages to fit? Or is it possible to wrap `include` with `ajax`  and I'm just doing it wrong?

Thank you

Comment: just out of curiosity... if you'll wrap the `p:datatable` with `<p:ajax event="rowSelect"` , will it work ? i mean , maybe its not working cause of the fact you wrapping `<ui:include` with `<p:ajax` all cause of the order of the JSF "XML DOM" build order ?

Comment: @Daniel. Tried it just now. Unfortunately it does not work, with the same error message. Makes me wonder why - as I mentioned in the comment, I thought that events get propagated to the parents...Btw, I have found a working solution - see my answer

Comment: Weird , cause you can wrap a `h:commandButton` with `f:ajax` for sure maybe its something primefaces related...

Comment: @Daniel - yeah, that's where I had my idea from :) I have seen it work with `f:ajax`. If you happen to find out, don't hesitate to tell, please.

Comment: I'd ask this question on primefaces forum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't because of **event="rowSelect"**. Some explanation of **event="rowSelect"** mean 'a row in the datatable is selected'. So you cannot use this outside of p:dataTable.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. my intuition was that events get propagated to parent elements, since you can wrap other elements with ajax tags. Do you happen to have an advice on that?

Comment: @kostja other components wrap p:ajax is worked but p:ajax wrap other components is doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a different approach for this - setting ui parameters for the facelet is definitely better than enforcing Ids for all views using the facelet.

One can safely leave the `<p:ajax>` tag inside the facelet table, just define a param on the inclusion site:

```
<ui:include src="/open/components/submittersTable.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="updateParam" value=":open:content" />
</ui:include>
```

and change the `updated` attribute to use this param:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="#{updateParam}" />
```